# My job booked my hotel room for me. Is it okay to ask the hotel receptionist to accommodate a specific room request?

Tags: travel

I am going on a work-related trip and my company has booked the hotel for me.

When checking in, I would like to ask the hotel receptionist if they can give me a “twin room”, i.e., a room with two separate, smaller beds, instead of a room with a single large bed. I checked the hotel website and I know twin rooms exist in the hotel they booked. The website suggests that the twin rooms are the same price as the other rooms with a single larger bed.

I desire this accommodation because I am bringing a companion with me to my trip, but we would prefer not to sleep in the same bed. My company knows I am bringing someone with me, but I believe they assumed that we’d be fine sharing a bed.

Of course, if the hotel cannot accommodate me, I will not complain and will move on with my back-up plan. But is it okay to ask at check-in?

I am sorry if this is a dumb question. This is my first job after an academic career and I am still learning the customs of the non-academic workplace. For reference, I am American, my coworkers are a mix of Americans and Western Europeans, and the hotel is in the UK.

Comment: Is this « companion » a work colleage? In which case your employer would have booked a twin or two rooms. Or is it a « friend « and your employer assumed partner by the way you asked?

Comment: @SolarMike Some partners prefer to sleep in a seperate bed.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie they may do, but still the employer may or did make an assumption… Down to the employee to check really.

Comment: @SolarMike "My company knows I am bringing someone with me, but I believe they assumed that we’d be fine sharing a bed." Sounds like the company assumed the OP and their companion wish to share a bed.

Comment: Have you considered asking your manager (or whoever approved your trip)? If not, why not?

Comment: It looks like you don't even know for sure that a room with one bed was reserved. Why don't you ask your company which kind of room they reserved and/or to reserve a twin room?

Comment: @SolarMike It is a non-romantic friend, and we prefer not to share a bed. (I was explicitly told that we were welcome to invite someone with us, but of course, most people invite their spouse/partner.) I am not proud of this, but I was embarrassed to ask about this, and since this is my first job, I was scared to draw unnecessary attention to myself by asking them to book a twin room.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie That's right. Most people bring a spouse. I invited a non-romantic friend because I am unmarried and didn't want to do my first international trip solo. I am also going a few days in advance and using PTO, so I wanted someone to join me for that part.

Comment: @newjob301 Is there a perception/expectation from the organisation that your "partner" is romantically involved with you, and you wish to avoid a line of enquiry that may bring that fact to light?

Comment: @Esther To be honest... I am kind of embarrassed that I invited a non-romantic friend to this work trip. I did it because I am using a few days of PTO to come in advance, and the location is a highly desirable place to do a vacation. I didn't want to do that part alone. Most people ended up not inviting anyone, so I guess I feel juvenile for inviting a non-spouse/partner (even though they said I could).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It is my perception that everyone will assume that my companion is romantically involved with me. This is our annual company meet up, and every other person's companion their romantic partner/spouse. I don't mind if they assume my companion is my boyfriend. My main worries concern around what the organizers might think (e.g., they may think I am being difficult? Or unreasonable)? While we were told that we could invite a "+1", I also worry that I made a faux pas by inviting a friend.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> But is it okay to ask at check-in?

Absolutely ! Most hotels will accommodate this without a second thought, especially if the rooms are the same price anyway. You can also call ahead or make a request on their website.

A few things to consider

1. Especially if this is your first business trip with your employer:
   familiarize yourself upfront with travel policies, the paperwork you need to
   file after you done (aka expense report). Makes sure you know what
   receipts you need or don't need and what can be expensed up to what limit.
2. If there is a price difference, you can choose to pay the adder by yourself. Ask your company upfront how they would like to handle the paperwork.  This could be either two different invoices or a single one with the higher amount and you paying a refund (or deducting from other expenses you pay out of pocket). Could also be that you pay the full amount upfront and that submit an expense for the original price. This all depends on how your company handles this
3. Don't do anything that violates the company's travel policy. If in doubt, just ask.
4. In some countries tipping (or bribing) the receptionists can help any request, but that's less the case in the UK
5. If your company allows you to setup a travel profile, make sure all your room preference is set properly. This way they will book your preferred room type next time automatically.
6. Enjoy the trip!

Comment: As someone who approves expenses in the UK, I can tell you that I would reject a bribe to  a receptionist, generally returning the claim with a request to delete the item as it was an optional spend not covered by policy. Likewise tips to taxi drivers, hotel staff, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think Hilmar was suggesting the bribe should be claimed as an expense. To be honest, as an employee, I wouldn't think to claim tips, let alone a bribe, unless there was a cultural expectation of either to occur. And if I did claim, I'd claim them as incidentals.

Comment: 0. Work with the travel folks to get your (air/car/hotel) preferences into their booking system (or go in and add them yourself).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, to that point, in the US it is very common to claim tips as normal expenses for meals, taxis, etc. It is culturally expected and considered just part of the cost of doing business. It would just be another line on the expense report if you need to itemize. The company expense guide will often have guidelines on how much tip is considered reasonable. But bribes are unacceptable, don't claim those.

Comment: @SethR In fact a bribe, even in a foreign country, could violate the Foreign Corrupt Practices Act for an American on business.  This isn't something anyone would make a court case about in this instance, but in general its to be avoided.

Comment: @SethR I think in the U.K., a tip would be covered under expenses for a meal, and that’s about it. It’s common to have the tip included in the bill by default for larger parties anyway.

Comment: @Tim, US tipping culture is weird, and not well understood by people in other countries. Heck, it's barely understood by people who live here. It doesn't really make sense. We also hate the metric system.

Comment: Like it or not: in some parts of the world tipping is required and a normal part of daily life.  In other parts its offensive and weird and in most parts its somewhere in between.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the UK in particular, but the line between a "bribe" and a "tip" can be fuzzy to nonexistant. E.g. I was advised to keep enough cash on hand to pay my way through Russia (uh, before the... recent situation) a couple bills at a time. Similarly to tips in the US, bribes were more or less required to earn a living wage. It's a grey area, so that kind of thing wouldn't be explicitly listed on an expense report, but travel budgets would reflect the actual expenses *somehow*.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's really unlikely that someone is going to be charged with a crime from the FCPA unless they are bribing officials to try to secure contracts. Most of the time overseas, you're paying a police officer a "fine" for speeding, or some other manufactured crime.

Comment: @RutherRendommeleigh The line between tips and bribes is, at least as far as the FCPA is concerned, not at all fuzzy. One does not "tip" government employees; that's a bribe. If you're giving money to a private individual, AFAIK that doesn't violate the FCPA. I suppose one could still consider it a bribe if the money is going to a employee to induce that employee to act against their fiduciary obligations, but paying an employee to do more work isn't a bribe.

Answer (score 19):

I guess if the prices are the same, then you can ask the hotel to switch the room, and pay nothing extra.

If the price of the 2-bed room is higher than the single-bed room, then perhaps, you can pay for the difference out of your pocket, and everything should be fine.

If the price of the 2-bed room is lower than the single-bed room, then perhaps, you should make sure that the company gets refunded for the price difference, and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 19):

> But is it okay to ask at check-in?

Contact the hotel directly before the trip. If the hotel is likely to fill before you arrive, there might not be the rooms you want at the time of check-in.

This assumes that you can see the rate that the company is paying. Sometimes the company/organizer reserves a block of rooms, and individuals make reservations against that block. Other times the company/organizer makes all the arrangements, and the participant never touches the reservation or has to pay any money.

If it is unclear talk to the organizer.

People modify room reservations all the time. They want to arrive a day early for sightseeing. They want to add a couple of days at the end for the same reason. Some need a handicapped room.  Some are willing to pay a few dollars out of their pocket for a suite versus a regular room. Some need to add a crib.

Comment: I agree that contacting the hotel before the trip is the sensible course.  However last year I arrived and checked into a "twin" room, only to find it had a double/queen bed.  One phone call to reception and two cheerful people came up to take off the sheets, push the beds apart & apply new sheets, instantly transforming it into a twin.